# Is the space of continuous functions on a compact set a complete space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

I have to demonstrate that the space of continuous real functions on a compact set, with respect to the norm $\|\cdot\|_{1}$ ($\mathcal{C}^{(0)}([a,b],\|\cdot\|_1)$), is not a complete space.

I used this argument: let $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of real functions
$$
f_n:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}; \qquad
f_n = \frac{x-a}{x-a+1/n}
$$
$f_n$ converges to $f$, where $f(x)=\frac{x-a}{x-a}=1\;\forall x\in(a,b]$. In fact
$$
\|f_n-f\|_1 = \int_{a}^{b}|1-\frac{x-a}{x-a+1/n}|dx = \frac{ln((b-a)n+1)}{n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow+\infty}0
$$
$f$ is not defined in $a$ (*not sure about this*), so $f_n$ is a Cauchy sequence that doesn't converge in $\mathcal{C}^{(0)}([a,b],\|\cdot\|_1)$ $\Rightarrow$ the space is not complete.

Is this demonstration correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Suggestion: find a sequence of cts functions which converge to a jump function.

Comment: @peterag I'll try, thanks! So this one was wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not correct. The sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges in $\mathcal{C}^{(0)}([a,b])$ to the constant function $1$.

You can take$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x<\frac{a+b}2-\frac1{2n}\\n\left(x-\frac{a+b}2\right)+\frac12&\text{ if }\frac{a+b}2-\frac1{2n}\leqslant x\leqslant\frac{a+b}2+\frac1{2n}\\1&\text{ if }x>\frac{a+b}2+\frac1{2n}.\end{cases}$$It is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal{C}^{(0)}([a,b])$, but it doesn't converge.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!